# i want the first element empty of a dropdown list

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm using a list to display all of the names of the application stored in the database. The problem is that I want the first element of the dropdown list to be empty.

```
<div class="col-lg-10">
                <select>
                    @foreach (var item in Model.Application)
                    {
                        <option value="@item.Application_Name">
                          @item.Application_Name
                        </option>
                    }
                </select>
</div>
```

At the moment the dropdown is working I just want the first element to be empty.

Comment: why don't you just add an empty `<option></option>` above your `@foreach`

Comment: i think you will need to use [html helper dropdownlist](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.webpages.html.htmlhelper.dropdownlist?view=aspnet-webpages-3.2) and pass a empty value in ```defaultOption``` parameter

Comment: <option value=""></option>

Comment: Exactly, if  I just use <option value=""></option>, It will show me an empty space but you still able to select that space

Comment: Just add text inside the options tag if you don't want it empty. `<option value="">Select application name</option>`